# How can I have all my SmartLabel emails tagged with 1 label in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I edit SmartLabel filters in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/34113/how-can-i-edit-smartlabel-filters-in-gmail)

I'm using the Gmail labs feature which adds SmartLabels such as "Promotion" and "Social Update" to relevant emails. I would like all SmartLabel emails archived/inbox skipped and all given a label (they can still keep the SmartLabel or not - I don't care). When I click on "edit" for each SmartLabel filter I get "Invalid search query - returning all mail." Any ideas?