# How can I edit SmartLabel filters in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I'm using the Gmail labs feature which adds SmartLabels such as "Promotion" and "Social Update" to relevant emails. I would like all SmartLabel emails archived/inbox skipped and all given a label (they can still keep the SmartLabel or not - I don't care). But when I click on "edit" for each SmartLabel filter I get "Invalid search query - returning all mail." Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I found this [about.com article](http://email.about.com/od/gmailtips/qt/How-To-Configure-Gmail-Smartlabels.htm) helpful for doing just that:

For example, to set up a filter for SmartLabel notifications, use:

```
label:^smartlabel_notification
```

then have it skip Inbox, etc.

Note: Gmail will warn you that this won't work for incoming emails but it does indeed work.

about.com for the win (never thought I'd say that)

Note: create a new filter, don't edit the SmartLabel one

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question, you might want to check this:

[image]

For the second part of your question, I suggest you select the Label - when it lists messages, select multiple messages (one each from Facebook, twitter, etc..) and click on More -> Filter Messages like these (and change FROM to *@facebook.com, *@twitter.com, ...) and choose a label - so basically you would have to create a new filter.

You could also have separate filters for Facebook, Twitter, Quora, ... and choose to move them to different labels, skip inbox (and optionally mark them as read) if you wish.

Comment: Where is that checkbox located?

Using filters for individual emails is not an option as I am a member of hundreds of mailing lists and forums etc, and I am always joining new ones.

Comment: Neither part of the user's question was answered; you didn't state where to find the checkbox, and the question as to how to edit a smart filter remains completely unaddressed.

Comment: @MyrddinEmrys It's been a while since this was answered. If you are looking for an answer, let me know and I can help you.